# Fast String "Startswith" Matching for Dict like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, startswith

I currently have some code which needs to be very performant, where I am essentially doing a string dictionary key lookup:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fast_lookup = {"a": 1, "b": 2}

    def bar(self, s):
        return self.fast_lookup[s]
```

`self.fast_lookup` has O(1) lookup time, and there is no try/if etc code that would slow down the lookup

Is there anyway to retain this speed while doing a "startswith" lookup instead? With the code above calling `bar` on `s="az"` would result in a key error, if it were changed to a "startswith" implementation then it would return `1`.

NB: I am well aware how I could do this with a regex/startswith statement, I am looking for performance specifically for startswith dict lookup

Comment: For a dict? No. I'd suggest using a different data structure.

Comment: What would you suggest? The data structure does not need to be a dict, just dict like as stated in the question; retain store and lookup features

Comment: A trie is the classic option. ShadowRanger suggested one module that provides a trie implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way to do this would be to use [the `pyahocorasick` module](https://pyahocorasick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to construct a trie with the possible keys to match, then use [the `longest_prefix` method](https://pyahocorasick.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#longest-prefix-string-integer) to determine how much of a given string matches. If *no* "key" matched, it returns `0`, otherwise it will say how *much* of the string passed exists in the automata.

After installing `pyahocorasick`, it would look something like:

```
import ahocorasick

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fast_lookup = ahocorasick.Automaton()
        for k, v in {"a": 1, "b": 2}.items():
            self.fast_lookup.add_word(k, v)

    def bar(self, s):
        index = self.fast_lookup.longest_prefix(s)
        if not index:  # No prefix match at all
            raise KeyError(s)
        return self.fast_lookup.get(s[:index])
```

If it turns out the longest prefix doesn't actually map to a value (say, `'cat'` is mapped, but you're looking up `'cab'`, and no other entry actually maps `'ca'` or `'cab'`), this will die with a `KeyError`. Tweak as needed to achieve precise behavior desired (you might need to use `longest_prefix` as a starting point and try to `.get()` for all substrings of that length or less until you get a hit for instance).

Note that this isn't the primary purpose of Aho-Corasick (it's an efficient way to search for *many* fixed strings in one or more long strings in a single pass), but tries as a whole are an efficient way to deal with prefix search of this form, and Aho-Corasick is implemented in terms of tries and provides most of the useful features of tries to make it more broadly useful (as in this case).

Comment: Thanks, a trie I think is what I was looking for as the "proper" solution and I did not know of this structure. The "cat", "cab" example is the behavior I would want, and in general there would be a "" catchall anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I dont fully understand the question, but what I would do is try and think of ways to reduce the work the lookup even has to do. If you know the basic searches the startswith is going to do, you can just add those as keys to the dictionary and values that point to the same object. Your dict will get pretty big pretty fast, however it will greatly reduce the lookup i believe. So maybe for a more dynamic method you can add dict keys for the first groups of letters up to three for each entry.

Without activly storing the references for each search, your code will always need to get each dict objects value until it gets one that matches. You cannot reduce that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I think a quick solution would be 

`if key in dict:`
    `return dict[key]`
`else:`
    `register(key)`

Where essentially register can be slow but will only be called once. Essentially a dynamic version of what you suggested, allowing it to not "know" all the possible keys first

Comment: @Helios You can use the dictonaries function .setdefault() which will do exactly that. It will either return the object at the key or set that kee to the value you provided and then return that. There is also a module which has a dictionary object called a defaultdict which is quite similar.